# Discord bot going through both paths in if/else statement?

Tags: java, api, discord

I'm working with discord api, and I'm trying to get my java bot to output a message based on what was sent to the channel. For some reason however, the bot appears to be going through both branches of the if/else statement which I didn't think was possible. My code for the class is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.*;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

//channel.sendMessage("Pong ").queue();
//Default Message sender. ^

public class EListener extends ListenerAdapter
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAuthor().isBot()) return; //This helps the bot ignore other bots who send messages that would interfere for some reason. If it is a bot, returns to start.

    Message message = event.getMessage(); //Sets the message equal to the variable type 'Message' so it can be modified within the program.
    String content = message.getContentRaw(); //Gets the raw content of the message and sets it equal to a string (best way to convert types Message to String).
    MessageChannel channel = event.getChannel(); //Gets the channel the message was sent in (useful for sending error messages).

    if(content.startsWith("!suspend"))//Pretty self explanatory. Enters the loop if the message begins with !suspend.
    {
        String[] spliced = content.split("\\s+"); //Splits the message into an array based on the spaces in the message.
        TextChannel textChannel = event.getGuild().getTextChannelsByName("ranked-ms_punishments",true).get(0); //If there is a channel called ranked-ms_punishments which there should be set the value of it equal to the variable.

        int length = spliced.length;//Sets 'length' equal to the number of items in the array.

        if(length == 3)//If the number of items in the array is 3 then...
        {
            if(spliced[1].startsWith("<"))
            {
                textChannel.sendMessage("nab").queue();//Sends the message in the quotations.

            }
        }else {
            channel.sendMessage("Please use the following format for suspending a user: '!suspend' <@user> (length)").queue(); //If length doesn't equal 3 then it sends the message in quotations.
        }
    }
}
```

}

As you can see, based on the code the bot should output 'nab' to the specified discord channel if the requirements in the loop are met (the length of the array being equal to three), and if these requirements are not met, it outputs an error messasge back to the user. For some reason, BOTH of these things are happening no matter if I fit the requirements or not. Is there some error in my code causing it to do this?

Edit: It's actually only doing both when I DON'T fit the requirements, but it doesn't send the error message when I DO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think method onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) is running twice,on one call condition of length is matching and on other call condition is not matching so you are getting both the outputs.